# Sobolev inequality and chain rule

Tags: sobolev-spaces, lp-spaces, weak-derivatives

> Suppose $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is a bounded open set with $C^1$ boundary. Suppose $u \in W^{1,3}(\Omega)$. Then prove that $u^2 \in W^{1,3}(\Omega)$ and we have the following estimate,
>
> $$ ||u^2||_{W^{1,3}(\Omega)} \leq C||u||_{W^{1,3}(\Omega)}^2 $$
> for some $C > 0$.

Proving that $u^2 \in W^{1,3}(\Omega)$ was a simple application of the chain rule for weak derivatives. For instance,
see here: [Chain rule in the Sobolev space $W^{1,p}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1110231/chain-rule-in-the-sobolev-space-w1-p).

I'm having difficulty with the estimate, however. Since $D(u^2) = 2uDu$, this amounts to showing that,

$$ ||u^2||^3_{L^3(\Omega)} + ||2uDu||^3_{L^3(\Omega)} \leq C\left(||u||_{L^3(\Omega)}^3 + ||Du||_{L^3(\Omega)}^3\right)^2 $$

I don't think we can use any embedding theorems here because we are in the case where $p = 3 > 2 = n$. [Morrey's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_inequality#Morrey%27s_inequality) would apply but that involves Holder norms. Are there any $L^p$ norm manipulations I can use like a variant of Holder's inequality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Morrey's inequality is in fact exactly what you need. If $u \in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$, $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^n$,  $p > n$, and $\lambda = 1 - \frac np$ then $u \in C^{0,\lambda}(\Omega)$ and $\|u\|_{C^{0,\lambda}(\Omega)} \le C \|u\|_{W^{1,p}(\Omega)}$. This validity of this inequality is the only point where the boundary condition on $\Omega$ is needed.

Functions in $C^{0,\lambda}$ are bounded.  In fact $\sup_\Omega |u| \le \|u\|_{C^{0,\lambda}(\Omega)}$.

That's about it. If $u \in W^{1,3}(\Omega)$ and $n=2$ then  $$\|u^2\|_{L^3(\Omega)} \le |\Omega|^{1/3} \sup_\Omega |u|^2 \le |\Omega|^{1/3} \|u\|^2_{C^{0,1/3}(\Omega)} \le C |\Omega|^{1/3}\|u\|^2_{W^{1,3}(\Omega)} $$
and
$$\|uDu\|_{L^3(\Omega)} \le \sup_\Omega |u| \|Du\|_{L^3(\Omega)} \le \|u\|_{C^{0,1/3}(\Omega)}\|u\|_{W^{1,3}(\Omega)} \le C \|u\|^2_{W^{1,3}(\Omega)}.$$

Comment: Thank you very much. I was able to follow everything except the inequality, $\sup_\Omega|u| \leq ||u||_{C^{0,\lambda}(\Omega)}$, which seems subtle. I can't quite see why, 

$$ \sup_\Omega |u| \leq \sup\limits_{x\neq y\in\Omega}\frac{|u(x)-u(y)|}{|x-y|^{\lambda}} $$

Comment: Ahh, I see it now. I forgot one part of the Holder norm:

$$ ||u||_{C^{0,\lambda}(\Omega)} = \sup_\Omega|u| + \sup\limits_{x\neq y\in\Omega}\frac{|u(x)-u(y)|}{|x-y|^{\lambda}} $$

Thanks again!