# Functional Space Inequality for Sobolev Space and Lp Space

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, lp-spaces, lipschitz-functions, functional-inequalities

Let $X = C_{0}(\Omega) := \{ u \in C(\overline{\Omega})\,|\,u|_{\partial\Omega}=0\}$ and define $F : X \to X$ as Lipschitz continuous function and $F(0) = 0$. Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^{N}$ be a bounded domain with Lipschitz continuous boundary and $u \in X\cap H_{0}^{1}(\Omega)$, show that $F(u) \in H_{0}^{1}(\Omega)$!

This is my attempt so far :
\begin{align*}
||F(u)||_{H_{0}^{1}}^{2} &= ||F(u)||_{L^{2}}^{2} + ||\nabla F(u)||_{L^{2}}^{2}\\
&:= A + B
\end{align*}

First, I show that $A$ is bounded. Observe that
\begin{align*}
A &= \int_{\Omega}|F(u)|^{2}dx \\
&\leq \int_{\Omega}(\sup\limits_{\Omega}|F(u)|)^{2}dx = \int_{\Omega}||F(u)||_{X}^{2}dx\\
&=|\Omega|\,||F(u)-F(0)||_{X}^{2}\\
&\leq |\Omega|(L||u-0||^{2}_{X})^{2} = L|\Omega|\,||u||_{X}^{2}<\infty
\end{align*}
Hence, $A$ is bounded.

Now, my problem is how to show that $B$ is bounded as well? Since $F$ is Lipschitz, is there anything I can say for $B := \int_{\Omega}|\nabla F(u)|^{2}dx$?

Any help is pretty much appreciated!

Comment: I think you made a mistake in the problem. Take any function $\phi\in X\setminus H^1(\Omega)$ and let $F(f)=f(p)\phi$ for some $p\in \Omega$. This map $F$ satisfies all you assumptions, yet $F(f)\notin H^1_0(\Omega)$ unless $f(p)=0$. Instead I think $f$ should be a map from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ and $F(u)$ denotes the composition of $u$ and $F$.

Comment: Thank you for your correction! So, supposing $F(u) : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, can I do something to prove the boundedness of $B$?

Comment: I think your question is answered here (in more generality): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1110231/chain-rule-in-the-sobolev-space-w1-p

Comment: From what I've seen, that question assumes the boundedness of $F$ as a once differentiable function. Can I assume the same thing given I have locally Lipschitz function? I know Lipschitz continuous function implies differentiability a.e. but I am not sure about the boundedness of derivatives

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1110231/chain-rule-in-the-sobolev-space-w1-p) one can find a proof under the assumption that $F$ is continuously differentiable. From here one can proceed by approximation.

Let $(\eta_\epsilon)_{\epsilon>0}$ be a mollifying kernel and $F_\epsilon=F\ast \eta_\epsilon-F\ast\eta_\epsilon(0)$. Then $F_\epsilon\in C^\infty$, $F_\epsilon\to F$ uniformly and $|F_\epsilon'|\leq L$, where $L$ is the Lipschitz constant of $F$. Since the energy functional $u\mapsto \int|\nabla u|^2$ is lower semicontinuous on $L^2$ (this is equivalent to the completeness of $H^1$), one has
$$
\int |\nabla (F\circ u)|^2\leq\liminf_{\epsilon\searrow 0}\int|\nabla (F_\epsilon\circ u)|^2=\liminf_{\epsilon\searrow 0}\int|F_\epsilon'\circ u|^2|\nabla u|^2\leq L^2\int|\nabla u|^2.
$$